# Replace the value of a column based on the a matching value of a adjacent columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

> Basically I want to replace the values of the 4th column with the numbers on the second one based on the matching country names.

```
Country Name    Country Code    Country Name    Country Code
Afghanistan       54             Afghanistan      AFG
Albania           55             Albania          ALB
Algeria           56             Algeria          DZA
American Samoa    57             American Samoa   ASM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the IF funtion: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

I don't have excel at hand at the moment, but it should be something like the following (assuming that the A1 is the header with "Country Name", put the following in the D2):
=IF(A2=C2,B2,"AFG")